# Implementation of regex matches highlighting in text editor

Tags: text-editor

I can't understand how text editor can update highlighting of regex while user typing - editing any char of text can change match - it's requeres to rescan all text on every user key pressing. But they do.

- Incremental perl-based regex? - they are not in nature
- Try to search after previous match? - previous and next matches can be missing or too far from screen that need to rescan biggest part of document, also regex with lookaround will be broken
- Another thread? - seems to be only true solution, but you receive annoying highlighting lag

  - may be possible to move old match highlighting manualy on user input (but we still have problem with new match highlighting/old highlighting removing lag)
  - may be search in screen buffer (most user regex consume short strings) and then run thread for highlighting to find other long matches with lag (better show highlight late than never)

I would like to know more about existent realizations.

For example, we have: 5,9 MB file (start with ABC, ends with abc) and 2 regex: `ABC(.|\n)*abc` and `using(.*?);`

- Sublime Text(regex1): regex out of stack space
- Sublime Text(regex2): lags ~300 ms, don't update screen untill key up
- EditPad Lite 7(regex1): ~500 ms lag on text input, if remove last 'c' - 5000 ms
- EditPad Lite 7(`ABC.*abc` - they use multiline dot): no lags! if remove last 'c' - lags 400ms.
- EditPad Lite 7(`ABC.*abc`, file 578,3 Mb): no lags. How?? Remove last 'c' - 50 seconds on input char
- EditPad Lite 7(regex2): no lags!
- Vim(regex1): maxmempattern, but if use `\(.\|\n\)*abc` - highlights if file scrolled to end, no lags, highlighting works until scroll up by 300 lines of 17445, then it's missing and don't went back. How it works?
- Vim(regex2): no lags, no bugs

Whole file scanning on every user entry:

- .NET Regex(regex1): ~300 ms lag on text input (if remove last 'c' from text - freezes forever)
- .NET Regex(regex2): ~300 ms
- .NET x86 PCRE clumsy 2-functions wrapper(regex1): fail with error
- .NET x86 PCRE clumsy 2-functions wrapper(regex2): ~300 ms

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested - I've used buffer with size = screen chars + stock (just don't highlight big matches)